# Clojure, redeclear variable causes warning "already refers to"

Tags: clojure

I began learning Clojure today and I ran into a problem that I would not solve with cleaver Googeling.

I have a simple script where I'd like to increase a counter when a condition is met. I've learned that variables are immutble in Clojure and the way around increasing this is to redeclear it, however this throws a warning.

```
(defn main[]
    (def num 0)
    (if [...]
        (def num (+ num 1))
    )
)
```

However this throws the following warning:

```
WARNING: num already refers to: #'clojure.core/num in namespace: user, being replaced by: #'user/num
```

Comment: small point that wasn't really relevant to answering this question: `[...]` will always be `true` as far as if is concerned, no matter what you put in the space of `...` (even nothing at all) `(if [] :yes :no) => :yes` `(if [false] :yes :no) => :yes` `(if [1 2 3] :yes :no) => :yes` etc. etc. etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two problems here:

One, you are shadowing a function in clojure.core. This gets a warning because it can lead to unexpected behavior. If you know you won't be using `clojure.core/num`, you can include the following in your namespace declaration:

```
(ns my.ns
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [num])
  ....)
```

Next problem: `def` is not for creating local values. Using def as anything other than a top level form is almost always a mistake, and any exceptions to this should require very explicit justification. It can only create global mutable `var`s. Use `let` for bindings that are specific to one scope, like inside a function.

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
  (let [num 0
        num (if ... num (inc num))]
    ...))
```

Here, num is not mutated, and not created as a global `var`, but it is a local binding that is shadowed by the second binding.

Comment: If you use the let instead of def, you don't need `:refer-clojure`.
But +1 for answering the actual question instead of a "why would you A"

Answer (score 0):

Short Version:

In Clojure there are special abstractions to represent something that changes over time. The simplest one is called an `atom`. You start the atom with a value `0`, and then you change the atom by applying the function `inc` to its value.

```clj
(def n (atom 0))

(def -main 
  [& [args]]
  (if condition
    (swap! n inc))
  ...)
```

Long Version:

If I understand correctly, you are asking for a way around immutability. This means that you are modelling some concept (i.e. site visitors) that takes different values (i.e 42) over time. Clojure is very opinionated on how to do this and the techniques it offers ([STM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory)) are central to the language. The reason Clojure works differently is to make concurrency easier but you do not need to think about to concurrency in order to increment a counter. To understand the rationale behind Clojure I recommend Rich Hickey's talks, in this case [The Value of Values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-6BsiVyC1kM).